# Extending Active Directory Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider, activedirectorymembership

I have an ASP.NET web site that will use Active Directory to store Users.
There is a requirement to allow users to use their emails as username.
Active directory will not allow characters like "@" in the usernames.
I created a class to extend the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider; It converts usernames from (user@domain.com to user_x0040_domain.com ) before calling the base class functions.
example:

```
  public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            string encodedUsername = this.Encode(username);
            return base.ValidateUser(encodedUsername, password);
        }
```

The Problem is that in the MembershipUser does not allow changing the username.
How can I handle overriding the methods that return MembershipUser?
Like MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do this overriding the MembershipUser returned by the Active Directory provider, something like this:

```
public class MyActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider : ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider
{
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser user = (ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser)base.GetUser(providerUserKey, userIsOnline);
        if (user == null)
            return null;

        return new MyActiveDirectoryMembershipUser(user);
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        MembershipUserCollection newColl = new MembershipUserCollection();
        foreach (ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser user in base.FindUsersByName(usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords))
        {
            newColl.Add(new MyActiveDirectoryMembershipUser(user));
        }
        return newColl;
    }

    // TODO: check other methods to override
}

public class MyActiveDirectoryMembershipUser : ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser
{
    private string _userName;

    public override string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
    }

    public MyActiveDirectoryMembershipUser(ActiveDirectoryMembershipUser user)
    {
        // TODO: do your decoding stuff here
        _userName = MyDecode(user.Email);
    }
}
```

NOTE: you will need to ensure all methods that return a user are overriden. It also has a some performance impact on collection methods, because you'll need to duplicate the collection (as I have shown in the sample).